# How to create and add values to a JavaScript Dictionary

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I'm trying to create a Dictionary with a key and a value list pair. I'm able to create a dictionary for a key value pair but I need to insert a list of Items as value for a key value. 
Here is my approach:

```
keys = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
Elements Corresponding to 'A' : 'apple'
Elements Corresponding to 'B' : 'ball', 'balloon','bear'
Elements Corresponding to 'C' : 'cat','cow'
```

and my result should be like:

```
{ key:'A' value:['apple'], key:'B' value:['ball',balloon','bear'], Key:C' value:['cat','cow']}
```

Here is just a sample data, I will get data dynamically from a table.Please help me out.Thanks In advance.

Comment: I don't really understand, it seems that you already answered your question. Just use an array as value for each key and append the items to the array.

Comment: I explained my problem with an example data... All I would get is a dynamic data. I don't even know how many elements would fall under a particular key value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code can add a new key-value pair into some dictonary like object.

```
var dictionary= {};
function insertIntoDic(key, value) {
 // If key is not initialized or some bad structure
 if (!dictionary[key] || !(dictionary[key] instanceof Array)) {
    dictionary[key] = [];
 }
 // All arguments, exept first push as valuses to the dictonary
 dictionary[key] = dictionary[key].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
 return dictionary;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the same way but i'm getting only keys not the list items.

Comment: I make the error in code, so it not append the items, just create the keys. I update the code - current version work as expect. Sorry.

Comment: I tried out your solution but Didn't work for me. I made a JSFiddle for your reference Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/Harikrishna/ZX8ne/3/

Comment: You miss the search conditions array and i swap the for loops
the working code is here http://jsfiddle.net/kbS76/

But if you try to use it in real app - not forget to add the code to exclude duplicate records if necessary.

Comment: Here I'm getting objects in list right.. How to access the values in that list...

Comment: you can access to array of values by using dictionary[key]

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Json](http://www.json.org/),

```
var xObj = {'A' : ['apple'] ,'B' : ['ball','balloon','bear'],'Ç' : ['cat','cow'] };
```

Comment: All I get is dynamic data.. I don't even know how many elements would be in a list. I will get a JSON Formatted data like {data:[{'key':'a',value:'apple'},{'key':'b',value:{'ball'},{'key':'b',value:'balloon'}]}

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
/* Define dictionary */
var dict = {};

/* Define keys */
var keys = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

/* Assign array as value for each key */
for (var n = 0; n < keys.length; n++) {
    dict[keys[n]] = [];
}

/* Make up a bunch of words */
var words = ["apple", "ball", "balloon", "bear", "cat", "cow"];

/* Append these words to the dictionary according to their first letter */
for (n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    dict[words[n][0].toUpperCase()].push(words[n]);
}
```